# Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debug not compatible platform error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, target, platform

I'm trying to remote debug a Visual Studio 2015 project and i get following strange error:

[image: Visual Studio Error incompatible platforms]

In english, it should sound like 'the operation failed because the debug object and the debugger are on incompatible platforms'

This error occur when pressing [F5] on Visual studio to start debugging.

Before to start debugging, the remote MsVsMon.exe shows as follow:
[image: MsVsMon correctly connected]

Conditions are following:

- remote computer:

  - windows 7 pro sp1 x64, english version
  - msVsMon.exe is run from a share of the local debugging computer (so both Remote debugger uses the same code)
- local debugging computer:

  - Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
  - Windows 10 Italian version
- when starting debug from Visual Studio, the user T*5\b*e connect to the remote MsVsMon.exe successfully, see log 'T*5\b*e    connected'

What is wrong?

- is it a problem of different windows version?
- is it a problem of different languages version?

My solutions contains:

- an exe x86: I tried to change to Any Cpu or X86 but I collected a
  worst '... DCOM error ...'
- many dll in C# and vb.net compiled as 'Any Cpu'
- some dll in C# compiled as 'X86'
- some dll in C++ compiled as "win32'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try by deleting CurrentSettings.vssettings

To find the location of this file, go to  Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Import and Export Settings. Typically it's found at: Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Settings

Comment: In which way the deletion of CurrentSettings.vssSettings should solve my problem? I think I will loss my customization. Do you know which is the setting should I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: the problem was that I run msVsMon.exe from my pc share starting the x64 version while my exe is compiled for x86. I changed the share to the parallel folder x86 and the new msVsMon.exe run without problem.

I can find two little issues on Microsoft messaging:

1. when the debug session starts with the error the message shown

> "the operation failed because the debug object and the debugger are on
>   incompatible platforms"

should be changed in

> "the operation failed because the debug object platform 'x86' and the
>   debugger platform 'x64' are incompatible"

2. starting the x86 version msVsMon.exe a messagebox notifies the user that x86 version will run only x86 exe, otherwise the x64 will run all platform versions ... by this example it seems not.